# Javascript: Counting each character and storing inside object by property name

Tags: javascript, object, properties

LEt's say I have an object like this

```
var obj = {"a":0, "b":0, "c":0,....., "z":0};
```

and a string

```
 var str1 = "banana";
```

How do I get the end result of obj to have

```
 var obj = {"a":3, "b":1,.....,"n":2};
```

)

Comment: You should post what you've tried. If you haven't tried, then please do and come back if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: I've added a plunk. See question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need that initial object, just use a reducer on the array of characters:

```
var charFreq = function(x) {
  return x.split('').reduce(function(acc, x) {
    return acc[x] = ++acc[x] || 1, acc
  },{})
}

console.log(charFreq('banana'))
//^ {b:1, a:3, n:2}
```

If you need the other letters with zero value you can extend an initial object with the result:

```
var abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  .split('')
  .reduce(function(a, x){return a[x] = 0, a},{})

var extend = function(x, y) {
  Object.keys(y).forEach(function(k){x[k] = y[k]})
  return x
}

extend(abc, charFreq('banana'))

console.log(abc)
//^ {a:3, b:1, ..., n:2}
```

Comment: That pretty much solves my entire problem. Thanks. But could you explain? I have no idea what ++acc[x] ||1, acc even means....

Comment: See if this helps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty to new to Javascript. I'm totally lost at what you did there with the charfreq function after the split part. I didn't understand 

1) Reduce
2) The line  return acc[x] = ++acc[x] || 1, acc
  },{})

Comment: Reduce is a higher-order function. It takes a function and applies it to each element in the array, passing along an accumulator, or first value of the array otherwise. In this case the accumulator is an empty object; if they key (letter) exists, then increment its value by one, otherwise set the value to one, then return the accumulator and go on the next element.

Comment: Check the wikipedia article on folding, it might help you visualize it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)